# How to format sql statement in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a small problem with formatting  in Python.
My code is:

```
sql_statement="""
INSERT INTO {target}.{table}
SELECT COL1,COL2
FROM {src}.{table}
WHERE Id = 999 """.format(table=table,src=src,target=target)
cur.execute(sql_statement)
```

Every time when i print this sql_statement INSERT,SELECT,FROM and WHERE are shifted by one tab right in the terminal. How can i format this correct?
Also if i put INSERT into a first like where sql_statement is INSERT is printed ok.

```
sql_statement="""INSERT INTO {target}.{table}
SELECT COL1,COL2
...
```

Comment: You've misspelled `INSERT`.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. SQL doesn't care about whitespace in the query.

Comment: But I don't see any reason why they would be indented by a tab if the code is as you show.

Comment: Yes this code works perfect and sql doesn’t  care about the TAB. But i am not sure why if i print the sql statement i get extra TAB in my print. It’s  not a problem in the working, problem is because i cannot figure out why print puts  extra space

Comment: Is the code inside a function definition? Is it indented there?

Comment: Prints fine and untabbed for me...

Comment: How do you print the statement?

Comment: @AnthonyPotter since your question has been closed I cannot answer here, but I [added my anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64748090/4349415) to the linked dupe.

Comment: Yes it’s  inside a function and inside a for loop