# Receiving error from sql, is it the sql command itself or something else entirely?

Tags: python, sql

I'm resorting to overflow as a last ditch effort. I have been facing this bug for an incredibly long time and I have had no luck. I will try anything.

My sql command is

```
update_query = """
UPDATE users_data
SET stocks = """+str(stock)+"""
WHERE id = """+str(userid)

cursor = connection.cursor(buffered=True)
cursor.execute(update_query)
connection.commit()
```

context:
the variable stock is a list before I use str() on it.
userid is an int before I use str() on it.
the column stocks has a datatype of mediumtext
the column id has a datatype of text

the error I receive is

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '['gme', '1']
> WHERE id = 407081272293326858' at line 2

Please help

Comment: You should use a format string or another approach to your query as this approach is vulnerable to sql injections.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9433548/3050664.

Comment: Learn to use parameters!