# Error executing complex sql query with Python

Tags: python, sql, insert

I have the following query:

```
sql_query = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp1

select top 100 * 
into #temp1
from some_table_A

select top 100 * from #temp1'
```

When I try to run it with:

```
conn_obj = some_function_to_create_conn_obj()
cs = conn_obj.cursor()
data = cs.execute(sql_query).fetchall()

conn_obj.close()
```

I end up with error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\some_user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3397, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-26-d6279d5d7e78>", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
    data = cs.execute(sql_query).fetchall()
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.
```

I also get error if I try to execute it with:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query, conn_obj)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\some_user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3397, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-30-59174146dbd6>", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
    df = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query, conn_obj)
  File "C:\Users\some_user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 436, in read_sql_query
    return pandas_sql.read_query(
  File "C:\Users\some_user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 2117, in read_query
    columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

This is probably due to SQL `insert` statement. Simple `select` queries are running fine. Is there a work around?

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you have is because you are using `'` to start and close a string with multiple lines.

There's a answer for that

[Python SQL query string formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243596/python-sql-query-string-formatting)

Comment: Thank you, I am actually reading sql query from file. I do not think formatting is the issue, since it runs find for just `select` statement.