# Best way of gluing strings in Python to compose SQL query

Tags: python, string-concatenation

I'm coming from PHP background. When composing SQL queries I tend to do something like this:

```
$query = '
SELECT
    *
FROM `table` AS t
WHERE 
    t.`categoryID` = '.$categoryID.'
';

if(!empty($recordID))
{
$query .= '
    AND t.`recordID` = '.$recordID.'
';
}

$data = $db->fetchAll($query);
```

What would be the best/most efficient way of doing this in Python?

Comment: What DB library are you using? Probably you should avoid string concatenation altogether as it risks introducing SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: To expand on @MarkByers comment: This is what the Psycopg people call a a naïve approach to the composition of query strings, e.g. using string concatenation - http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters . Instead use query parameters to avoid SQL injection attacks and to automatically convert Python objects to and from SQL literals. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134691/python-string-formats-with-sql-wildcards-and-like?rq=1#comment24606225_3134691

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many way you can achieve it using Python. The simplest would be to either use the [format string syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) or the [Template](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#template-strings) object.

The advantage of the format string syntax is that you don't need to use another object. Example:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM `table` AS t WHERE t.`categoryID`={}".format(category_id)
if record_id:
    query += " AND t.`recordID`={}".format(record_id)
```

Although most of the time the database Python wrapper will let you make it more secure (preventing SQL injection):

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE Writers SET Name = %s WHERE Id = %s", ("Leo Tolstoy", "1"))
```

You maybe interested in these links:

- [A good way to escape quotes in a database query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897020/a-good-way-to-escape-quotes-in-python)
- [py-postgresql parameterized statements](https://py-postgresql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/driver.html#parameterized-statements)

Here is how it can work for Postgresql:

```
ps = db.prepare("SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = $1 LIMIT $2")
ps("tables", 1)
```

Comment: I like this solution much better. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Make sure you properly escape though, otherwise you may have SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks, I take it escaping method in your second example should be sufficient?

Comment: Yes! What database are you using? You maybe interested in this discussion too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897020/a-good-way-to-escape-quotes-in-python

Comment: I suppose `f''` instead of `format` will also prevent sql injections ? Aren't both the same?

Answer (score 5):

Use the python DB-API parameter substitution:

```
symbol = 'IBM'

# Do this 
t = (symbol,)
c.execute('select * from stocks where symbol=?', t)

# Larger example
for t in [('2006-03-28', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000, 45.00),
          ('2006-04-05', 'BUY', 'MSFT', 1000, 72.00),
          ('2006-04-06', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500, 53.00),
         ]:
    c.execute('insert into stocks values (?,?,?,?,?)', t)
```

From:
http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: That's a nice solution but it's not really what I was looking for. What I like about the way I do it in this PHP example is that it is very easy to follow the logic for complex queries that change based on some data.