# Python - single quotes within a SQL query

Tags: python, sql, escaping

I'm new to python and having some problems escaping characters in a SQL query (MSSQL 2008 R2).  There are lines in the file I'm using as input for the query string that have single quotes, parentheses and other characters.  They are TV and movie titles:

Tyler Perry's Daddy's Little Girls

Gamer - 3D

American Reunion ('12) (Unrated)

Jarhead 2: Field Of Fire (Unrated)

I'm not quite sure how to do the escape characters properly.  Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pyodbc


BASE_QUERY = """
SELECT AssetID,AssetName,AssetTypeID,DescriptorXML
FROM AssetLibrary.dbo.ALAsset with(nolock)
WHERE IsDeleted = 0
and (AssetTypeID = 1 or AssetTypeID = 4)
and AssetName like '%%%s%%'
"""

List = []

with open ("C:/Users/josh/Desktop/title-list.txt", "r") as potato:
    with pyodbc.connect(DSN='SQL-v13') as con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        for line in potato:
            query = BASE_QUERY % line
            cur.execute(query)
            results = list(cur.fetchall())
            if len(results) > 0:
                List.append(results)
```

Comment: don't do `query = BASE_QUERY % line` try: `cur.execute(BASE_QUERY,(line,))`

Comment: In particular, this answer addresses your situation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3134756/2337736