# How to match python strings similar to like in mysql

Tags: python, regex

```
a = "This is some text"
b = "This text"
```

I want to compare the variable b in a and should return true even if the text contains more than two words like

```
a = "This is another text here"
b = "This another here"
```

even if I compare b in a should return true in python

**Condition**: `True` == All words in `b` found, the same order, in `a`.
In the above examples, the words have to be in the same order and upper/lowercase.

Comment: are they letters or words count is greater than 2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python String Formats with SQL Wildcards and LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134691/python-string-formats-with-sql-wildcards-and-like)

Comment: i want to search like this -  This%text in python

Answer (score 1):

```
a = "This is some text"
b = "This text"

c = 0 
for i in b.split(): # check for each word in a
    if i in a: c = c + 1 # if found increases the count
c>=2 # true
```

or

```
len([value for value in a.split() if value in a.split()]) >= 2
```

Comment: i want it in regular expression. similar to like in mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can mimic the behavior to a certain extent using `regex`.

```
import re

def is_like(text,pattern):
    if '%' in pattern:
        pattern = pattern.replace('%','.*?')
    if re.match(pattern,text):
        return True
    return False


a = "This is another text here"
b = "This%another%here"
print(is_like(a,b))
>>>>True
a = "Thisis sometext"
b = "This % text"
print(is_like(a,b))
>>>>False
a = "Thisis sometext"
b = "This%text"
print(is_like(a,b))
>>>>True
a = "This is some text"
b = "This text"
print(is_like(a,b))
>>>>False
```

Note that I have not implemented any escaping for `%` character, so searching for `%` won't work.