# Send a Wildcard Characters in python sql query through %s

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Code looks like this:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="yourusername",
  passwd="yourpassword",
  database="mydatabase"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = """SELECT * FROM customers WHERE address LIKE '%way%'"""

mycursor.execute(sql)

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
  print(x)
```

This will select all the records whose address contain care like "way".

How to insert the wildcard dynamically by using %s

Basically I want to know how to use %s instead of 'way' in python so that the code will be more flexible.

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134691/python-string-formats-with-sql-wildcards-and-like

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
 query ="SELECT * FROM customers   WHERE\
 address LIKE '%"+variable+"%'"
```

Comment: Quite sure the question asks 'how to use %s', not how to concatenate string.

Comment: How to use %s and passing the parameter to cursor.execute() to avoid any SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the percentage by doubling them.

```
>>> res = """SELECT * FROM customers WHERE address LIKE '%%%s%%'""" % ('way')
>>> res
"SELECT * FROM customers WHERE address LIKE '%way%'"
```

Comment: Hi. How do I pass 'way' in cursor.execute(). That would prevent SQL injections