# How to do a SQL query using a string wildcard and LIKE?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am new to python and currently learning to use SQL with python. I have the following code:

```
word = input("Enter a word: ")
query = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Dictionary WHERE Expression LIKE '%s%' " % word)
results = cursor.fetchall()
```

The second line throws an error since I don't think I can use '%s%' like that? How would I change this so as to be able to make this work? I want to be able to return all related entries to the users input. So if the user inputs "rain", then I want the query to return all possible results e.g. "raining", "rainy" etc. Thank you.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python String Formats with SQL Wildcards and LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134691/python-string-formats-with-sql-wildcards-and-like)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
query = cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM Dictionary WHERE Expression LIKE '%{word}%' ")
```

Comment: This is insecure and vulnerable to SQL injection when used with untrusted input.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `cursor.execute()` parameter substitution rather than string formatting, to prevent SQL injection.

Then use `CONCAT()` to surround the search string with `%`.

```
query = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Dictionary WHERE Expression LIKE CONCAT('%', %s, '%' "), (word,))
```