# Why am I getting this sqlite3.ProgrammingError error?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, flask

The error is:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.
```

And this is the code causing it:

```
data = c.execute('''SELECT * FROM job WHERE title LIKE "%?%"''', (user_input,)).fetchall()
```

For more context, I'm trying to create a functioning search bar with Python, Flask and SQlite3, where c.execute here is supposed to return the data from my database based on user input. But I'm having trouble configuring `SELECT` so it works with partial matches too, hence the use of `LIKE`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thank you! Is it '''SELECT * FROM job WHERE title LIKE ''%' || ' ? || '%''''' or? Because this here is now throwing the sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error. I tried using the """quotes""" for SELECT, as well. Same thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python String Formats with SQL Wildcards and LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134691/python-string-formats-with-sql-wildcards-and-like)

Comment: The immediate problem is that `?` doesn't create a binding. For that you want `%s`, but that's a little awkward here because of the `%` in the syntax of the LIKE operator. For ways to solve that, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3134756/765091. Don't use insecure string manipulation as suggested in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else ends up having issues with this, please refer to [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67382767/8030746) In short, this can be done using format.

In my case it was:

```
data = c.execute("SELECT * FROM job WHERE title LIKE '%{}%'".format(user_input)).fetchall()
```

Comment: That's vulnerable to SQL injection: consider what happens when a malicious user's input is `x%'; DROP TABLE important_data; SELECT * FROM job WHERE title LIKE '%x`. It's much safer to avoid string manipulation and use the approach here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1. To handle the `%` character, one approach is shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62347841/765091

Comment: Oh, got it. Thank you for the comment. However, the approach you linked and that Barmar is suggestion is still giving me a syntax error.

Comment: You're right, there's a missing `)` after the `CONCAT` in Barmar's answer there. So you could fix that or alternatively use the approach here that does the concatenation in Python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3134756/765091